# RenderSection(string contentName, bool isRequired) method: Does it renders all the content sections

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Does the RenderSection(string contentName, bool isRequired) method renders all the content sections mentioned in the method?

My _PageLayout.cshtml has the following section

```
<div data-role="content">
    @RenderSection("ContentSection", true)
</div>
```

so, does all the `ContentSection`in all the cshtml files are rendered automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Sections are unique; you cannot define two sections in the same page with the same name.

If you try, you'll get an exception.

Comment: I have defined sections with same name but in different cshtml files its working fine.

Comment: @social: Yes; they're unique per-file.  You can't haev two sections with the same name _at once_.